browse, read, write and rename files in archives, not mount - mc & dolphin
the computer runs a linux kernel and kde6. i use the dolphin filemanager.
mark files, add them to an archive is a very usefull option.
dolphin can go into archivefiles, but it would be very usefull for me to rename files in the archives, add and or delete files in archives. How can i do that? do i need any plugin or something else? is there any other filemanager for they can do this? is this what i am looking for with midnight commander possible? i know that mc can go into archivefiles and iso files, but rename, delete and add can i not make in mc.
i have found some soloutions like avfs, fuse-mount and archivemount. but i have very much archive files, thats not a good way for me to mount them all. i will browse into the files they i need. i will not mount an archive as an folder. i have many .tar and .zip and some .rar archivefiles, but i can all of them convert to any other archiveformat is the required.

no one have an idea?

i can not belive that this im impossible...
